# ASP.NET 5 dependency error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I just started a new ASP.NET empty project. I'm getting the following error when trying to run the site:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Clr' or one of its dependencies.
```

My **project.json** file:

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta7-12119",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta7-12492",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta7-14376",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta7-13465",
    "Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection": "1.0.0-beta7-11621"

  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
  },

  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ]
}
```

My **Startup.cs** file:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.Run(async context => await context.Response.WriteAsync("aaa"));   
}
```

Comment: Could be related to this: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/44

Comment: @tugberk yep, it seems related. I'll keep an eye on this issue.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to the fact that Visual Studio 2015 tooling is not compatible with beta7 today. For more info and changes, you can keep an eye on this issue: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/44